# How can I bind data to a ComboBox inside from DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, data-binding, binding

This is the user control which I'm working on. The items in the first comboBox are gonna be the same in dataGridColumn GroupID.

[image]

The code to show in the first comboBox is

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="GroupComboBox" SelectedValuePath="GroupID" DisplayMemberPath="GroupName" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" />

    private void LoadGroups()
    {
        NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();

        var groups = (from p in dc.Group
                      select p);

        this.DataContext = groups;
    }

    private void LoadStudents()
    {
        NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();

        var students = (from p in dc.Student
                         select p);

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = students;
    }
```

But in the another comboBox, don't appear any item in it.

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="GroupID">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedValuePath="GroupID" DisplayMemberPath="GroupName" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

How can I bind it?

I was thinking in put all the Groups in a list, but I'm not sure it'll be a good way because I'd need to convert my query in a list.

**UPDATE 1:**

I had to remove this line:

```
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="GroupID" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" SelectedValuePath="GroupID" DisplayMemberPath="GroupName" />
```

for

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="GroupID">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" SelectedValuePath="GroupID" DisplayMemberPath="GroupName" SelectedValue="{Binding GroupID}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I would suggest retagging with WPF as the different UIs are very different when it comes to binding. Thanks.

Comment: Edit the tags on this post to include WPF, you might also want to remove database and/or linq. Properly tagging your question is very important to attract the right gurus to your post.

Comment: Ohh that's right, I forgot the most important tag

Comment: There are at least over 9000 questions here about binding ComboBoxes in a DataGrid, please look around for a bit...

Comment: @H.B. will you post some of them?

Comment: @oscar.imbres: [Here's a search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wpf+databinding+%2Bcombobox+%2Bdatagrid&submit=search) that lists a few.

Comment: @H.B. I can't fix my problem yet. I'm confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding of your internal ComboBox will not work because the DataContext of that ComboBox is your `Groups` collection but one of the `Students`, this means setting the `ItemsSource` to `{Binding}` will make the `Student` the `ItemsSource`.

You can navigate up the Tree with a RelativeSource binding to a place where the inherited `DataContext` is still the `Groups` collection, e.g. if the [inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197.aspx) is not blocked by setting the `DataContext` inbetween this will work:

```xml
{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}
```

Comment: It's not working yet. The first ComboBox is okay, but the another not. Do you think is wrong that I do this?

this.DataContext = groups;

Comment: @oscar.imbres: Yes it is, but my binding was aimed to account for that. Do you set the DataContext at any point in the tree between the UserControl and the DataGrid?

Comment: @oscar.imbres: You could just change the `AncestorType` to `UserControl`, the it will navigate to the top and get `this.DataContext` there, this may be a bit more performance intense though. (The reason i said that `this.DataContext` is wrong is because you normally want UserControls to be able to inherit te DataContext from outside. If you set it that will not work)

Comment: @oscar.imbres: Check for binding errors in the output window and tell me what they are.

Comment: Oh yeah, it worked out. But I cannot understand. Why didn't it work with DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Check my update

Comment: @oscar.imbres: DataGridComboBoxColumns are abstract objects, they do not appear on the user-iterface as they only govern how things are created, the RelativeSource binding has no tree to walk up. The template on the other hand with its embedded binding will eventually be placed in the visual tree, hence it works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Group class and in that class include a public List Students.  I don't have the same names but I am doing functionally what (I think) you are asking.  In this example each workflow as multiple batches.  The second list box binds to the selected item in WFEnum.  You need to use SelectedItem.Students to get the Student collection of the selected Group.  This is from working production code.  ElementName is what tells it to bind to the control.

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Name="WFEnum" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchItem.SrchWorkFlows}"  
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"}">
    ...
    <ListBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Name="WFBatchEnum"  
             ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Batches, ElementName=WFEnum}"
             DisplayMemberPath="BatchName" SelectedValuePath="ID"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Hope this helps the class Workflow.  Notice the WorkFlow has a public list Batches (for you students).  Notice in the case I only get the students from SQL on demand but once I get them I save the list and next time don't go back to SQL.  WPF and data binding is kind of complex but it is cool.

```
    public class Workflow : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Int16 id;
        private string name;
        private string description;       
        private Boolean active;
        private User createdBy;
        private DateTime createDate;
        private List<WFBatch> batches = new List<WFBatch>();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

        public Int16 ID { get { return id; } }
        public string Name { get { return name; } }
        public string Description { get { return description; } }           
        public Boolean Active { get { return active; } }
        public User CreatedBy { get { return createdBy; } }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get { return createDate; } }
        public WFBatch newWFbatch { get { return new WFBatch(this, App.StaticGabeLib.Search.IncludeFamilySrched); } }
        public List<WFBatch> Batches 
        {
            get
            { 
                // get the latest from SQL 
                // todo optimize - this for now will a SQL call for all batches here
                if (batches.Count > 0) return batches;
                SqlConnection sqlConnRW2 = new SqlConnection(sqlConnStringLibDef);
                try
                {
                    sqlConnRW2.Open();
                    SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand();
                    sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlConnRW2;
                    SqlDataReader rdr;
                    sqlCmd2.CommandText = sqlCmd2.CommandText = "Select [ID] from [wfBch] with (nolock) " + Environment.NewLine +
                        "where [wfID] = '" + ID.ToString() + "'  order by [ID] ";
                    rdr = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        batches.Add(new WFBatch(this, rdr.GetInt16(0)));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    sqlConnRW2.Close();
                }  
                return batches;
            }
        }
        public Workflow(Int16 ID, string Name, string Description, Boolean Active, User CreatedBy, DateTime CreateDate)
        {
            id = ID;
            name = Name;
            description = Description;
            active = Active;
            createdBy = CreatedBy;
            createDate = CreateDate;
            // WFBatch wfBatch = new WFBatch(this);
            // todo retreive batches
        }          
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to get it. Sorry, I'm still a newbie in WPF